# How do I get Javascript Sets/Maps to test for object/array equality?

Tags: javascript, set, equality

In Javascript, I know that `{foo: 'bar'} !== {foo: 'bar'}`.  That's fine, and if I really want to check if two objects are equal, I can write my own utility method that loops through the properties.  But what if I want to use objects or arrays in a `Set`, or as the keys in a `Map`?

I want some way so that this code works as expected:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set({foo: 'bar'}, 2);
map.get({foo: 'bar'}); // returns 2
```

Comment: That is simply not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: You need to write your own `Set` and `Map` with customisable equality checks